Problems using SDMX with PowerBI using Eurostat International Trade Data
I am able to use the following to get data from Eurostat in a CSV file form which I can open in EXCEL - https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/comext/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/data/ds-045409/M.BE.WORLD.73061100.1+2.VALUE_IN_EUROS/?format=sdmx-csv&startPeriod=2024-01&endPeriod=2024-03
enter image description here
However, when I use this in Power BI using the SDMX connector, the table displayed just shows errors instead of values.
SDMX.Contents(https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/comext/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/data/ds-045409/M.BE.WORLD.73061100.1+2.VALUE_IN_EUROS/?format=sdmx-csv&startPeriod=2024-01&endPeriod=2024-03, "Show labels only", "en")
enter image description here
Any ideas what I am doing wrong so that it does not work in PowerBI?
I tried to perform the query directly and resulted in the CSV file being downloaded which had the correct data.

Issues with connectivity or format can occasionally make using Power BI's SDMX connector difficult. You may fix these problems and effectively integrate Eurostat data into Power BI by confirming the URL, looking for network restrictions, looking over error messages, and possibly using different ways to import the data. An efficient remedy if the direct use of the SDMX connector continues to be difficult is to import the CSV file using Power Query or an automated download script.
a script can help automate the process:
url = "https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/comext/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/data/ds-045409/M.BE.WORLD.73061100.1+2.VALUE_IN_EUROS/?format=sdmx-csv&startPeriod=2024-01&endPeriod=2024-03"
response = requests.get(url)

with open('eurostat_data.csv', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)


Thanks - you nudged me in teh right direction and I was able to solve this using  Csv.Document(Web.Contents("https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/comext/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/data/ds-045409/M.BE..73061100.1+2.VALUE_IN_EUROS/?format=sdmx-csv&startPeriod=2021&endPeriod=2023"),10,",",ExtraValues.Ignore,1252)

It will be great if you think i helped you get the solution , just vote  my answer which will really help me grow in this technology.
